# How can I apply mutliple filters on my sql tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, filter, relational-division

I am struggling with what looks to be relational division in sql. I need to filter data from the same table based on multiple criteria. Here-under is a schema of what my table looks like.

```
| -------|----------------|-----------------|----------------|
|ID      |Question        |RespondentId     |Answer          |
| -------|----------------|-----------------|----------------|
|1       |Big             |1                |Yes             |
|2       |Big             |2                |Yes             |
|3       |Big             |3                |No              |
|4       |Gender          |1                |Male            |
|5       |Gender          |2                |Female          |
|6       |Gender          |3                |Female          |
|7       |Children        |1                |No              |
|8       |Children        |2                |Yes             |
|9       |Children        |3                |No              |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need the *RespondenId*s from this table called *Answers* that match the following filters : *Question* = *Big* and *Children* and *Answer* = *Yes* and *Yes* respectively for every question. Therefore, if I would have a correct Sql query my result should return me the following array : **[2]** since the only row that has the answer *Yes* for the question *Big* and the answer *Yes* for the question *Children* is the one with *RespondentId* = 2.

Also, the questions and the answers provided are not fixed and should be modular. For instance, I should be able to change an answer or removing a question without having to change the whole structure of my query.

Could you please help me finding a correct query for this problem ? I have been looking to a lot of explanations provided by @Erwin Brandstetter but none of them match my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select a.RespondentId 
from Answers a
when (question, answer) in ( ('Big', 'Yes'), ('Children', 'Yes') )
group by RespondentId
having count(*) = 2 ;
```

This is easily generalized to:

```
with qa as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('Big', 'Yes'), ('Children', 'Yes')
     ) v(question, answer)
select a.RespondentId 
from Answers a join
     qa
     on a.question = qa.question and a.answer = qa.answer
group by RespondentId
having count(*) = (select count(*) from qa);
```

This is pretty generalizable.  You could even arrange the CTE to take an array or json argument and parse out into the separate comparison values.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for result that having a count = 2 for the rows that match the question and answer  where  condition

```
select RespondentId 
from Answers 
when question in ( 'Big', 'Children')
and Answer ='Yes' 
group by RespondentId having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @scaisEdge but in this case, if I want my answer to the children question to be 'No' I am stucked with this structure of the query..

Comment: @MartinDelobbe   . my answer is right or not ..  ??

Comment: It answers the first part of my question but not the second one about the modularity

Comment: A query is a query  .. and filter based  on condition  .. you can't have a query the manage all the condition  ..  .. this is the SQL way of thinks  ... .. you should take a deep look at set Theory for manage correcly SQL

Comment: That's for sure but your answer is too specific for my use case. However, if you have an other solution in mind, I would be very happy!

Comment: Seems you wan't  undestand  ..anyway .. the answer  return the right value .. and this is the  important think

Comment: it's not a problem if it is too difficult for you. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to Pivot the table. There are different syntaxes for different databases. You effectively turn the values of the "Question" column into columns of their own and then look for the rows matching your criteria.

Here is an inefficient example in standard SQL where I create one table for each question and join them into a single table using the RespondentId.

`select respondent_id from
   (select * from answers where question = 'Big') as big
join
   (select * from answers where question = 'Children') as children
on
   big.respondent_id = children.respondent_id
where
   big.answer = 'Yes'
   and
   children.answer = 'Yes';`